# Install latest cppunit in windows

Tags: c++, windows, installation, cppunit

I am trying to install CppUnit on Windows.

I have downloaded it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/), decompressed it, and noticed that all files have ,v in their name, and no extension.

The instructions for installation (in included files, as well as on every site I found that suggests installation for **Windows**, are for Linux. ([example installing CppUnit for Windows Instructions](http://code.google.com/p/tonatiuh/wiki/InstallingCppUnitForWindows)).

Others, just to build: ([example: installing CppUnit for Visual Studio Instructions](http://www.danstechden.com/2009/11/19/using-cppunit-with-visual-studio/) or [Second answer on same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094133/how-to-install-cppunit-for-visual-c-2005)).

The accepted answer on the above link has a comment saying that the person who accepted it "Sorted it, I downloaded another version" - after he had exactly the same problem as I did - but did not specify what version or from where...

The link I have above is the latest version.

I was able to find a very old version, 1.12.1, from 2008, that would almost build (with lots of errors), on Windows. I am using it now to learn how to implement CppUnit. Still, it is 4 years old... I would like to be able to use the latest build...

Please, can someone give me some suggestion that I can implement, and works, in Windows, to install the latest cppUnit ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first download you made is an archive of the CVS repository. This explains the strange ,v "extensions" you see on the files. It is not what you should download. And indeed, the correct download you made (version 1.12.1) is 4 years old. It was the latest stable version though, so it should normally build. I don't know what the exact problems were you encountered.

There are however two newer options. There is CppUnit2, which is [available here](https://launchpad.net/cppunit2). And there is an independent fork of the original project [available here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/cppunit).

Perhaps you can check either of those out and see if they are less problematic for you.

Comment: The freedesktop version has in the git repos Visual Studio project files that work from MSVC 6 up till 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The fork Bart mentions on freedesktop.org appears to be the (only?) continuation of CppUnit version 1, and at this moment has version 1.13.2.
Note that for this version, if you want to use the test runner on Win64, you'll have to make a small modification described [here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81433) until that has made it to a newer release.